# Sync Job from MS Access File to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, ms-access, database-design, cron, jobs

I am trying to synchronize data from a MS Access Database to a MySQL database periodically(Every 10 Minutes).

Kindly suggest a method to the same and schedule it,

MYSQL version - 5.7, running on Linux

Comment: Which is the "source of truth"?  Access or MySQL?

Comment: Better infos, will cause better answers. Give a summary of what you are doing, infrastructure, amount of data., ..

Comment: MS Access is my primary data source, one of the RFID scanner is inputting data into the MS access Database.  There is a web application, working on MYSQL needs to consume this data. So I am trying to sync the data on every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a form that will always be open? Use a global variable and public functions with the Timer function which will allow you to run a procedure ever "N" min/hrs/days/etc or the Time function which will allow you to run a procedure when the time = "N".